# Pug render Mongoose: Error "cannot display [X] of undefined" but field is optional in schema and empty in some docs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

Noob here building a simple DB site with Mongoose, Express, Pug and Node.
I'm emulating Mozilla's "Local Library" site [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs), in case you're familiar with that.
My Model has an optional field that links to another Model doc like so:
`brand: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand'},`
Some docs for this model have a Brand and some don't.
In my Pug template I want to show a url virtual for the Brand if the doc has one:
`a(href=ingredient.brand.url) #{ingredient.brand.name}`
...But just return a blank "" if not.
I keep getting:
*'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "Brand"'*
I can't seem to get an If statement to work here. How does one usually handle this? Code in the Controller? In the Template? Am I trying to do something impossible?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Need more code where you are using the value and error throwns

Answer (score 0):

another noob but reading your question it sounds like if you put an if statement that checks to see if brand is undefined, then if its undefined it past that schema, but if there is a brand then it places it where it needs to go. again I'm a noob to so idk if this will help.